# How can I split a field of mixed names into first and last where no delimiter exists?

Tags: sql, database, parsing

I have a dataset with 1 million records, which I need to split the names of people into first and last.

My challenge is that the column `Last` contains business names and personal names, many with no delimiter.

Is this possible?

Example:

| Last | First |
| --- | --- |
| James Brown |  |
| Dicks Sporting Goods |  |
| Charlie Chaplin |  |
| Five Guys Burgers and Fries |  |
| Bob Newhart |  |
| Big Lots |  |

Desired Result:

| Last | First |
| --- | --- |
| Brown | James |
| Dicks Sporting Goods | Null |
| Chaplin | Charlie |
| Five Guys Burgers and Fries | Null |
| Newhart | Bob |
| Big Lots | Null |

Records with a delimiter are solved.

I'm struggling to see what criteria I can use to split the rest.

I took care of the simple stuff (delimited, obvious organization names) like this:

```
WITH FirstName_CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        IndexID, VALUE,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IndexID ORDER BY IndexID) AS RowNum
    FROM 
        jw_render
    CROSS APPLY
        STRING_SPLIT(Last, ',')
    WHERE 
        (LEN(LAST) < 35) 
        AND (Last LIKE '%,%' AND LAST NOT LIKE '%Medic%') 
        AND (Last LIKE '%,%' AND LAST NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%') 
        AND (Last LIKE '%,%' AND LAST NOT LIKE '%INC%') 
        AND (Last LIKE '%,%' AND LAST NOT LIKE '%LLC%') 
        AND (Last LIKE '%,%' AND LAST NOT LIKE '%Department')
)
-- Use the CTE in an UPDATE statement
UPDATE jw_render
SET LastName = PivotResult.LastName, 
    FirstName = PivotResult.FirstName
FROM jw_render
JOIN
    (SELECT 
         IndexID,
         [1] AS LastName, [2] AS FirstName
     FROM 
         FirstName_CTE
     PIVOT
         (MAX(VALUE)
          FOR ROWNUM IN ([1],[2])) AS PVT
         ) AS PivotResult ON jw_render.IndexID = PivotResult.IndexID;
```

Comment: Hi - if you can’t define the rules for how to split the fields then no one can help you implement the rules in SQL

Comment: You can't do that with SQL and if you check that data, it's not just First/Last name. Some values are company names, some will be in *reverse* order. And in some languages, eg Arabic, the entire line is the name, not just one of the words. You need to use an algorithm that can actually recognize the parts of each value. That's text-processing/machine learning territory but fortunately, there are a lot of libraries written in Python for this. SQL Server's Machine Learning Services allow running Python scripts on SQL Server data to

Comment: A trick that might help with this, `LEN(Last) - LEN(REPLACE(Last, ' ', ''))` will return how many spaces--and, thus, (words - 1)--are present in the column. This or course assumes single spacing, no tabs or CR/LFs, etc. Breaking the problem down into sets of 2, 3, 4, 5+ words might help.

Comment: And, yes, as the others have and will say, this is a largely intractable problem that could require a LOT of manual hands-on work and review. (One reason I'd break it into smaller, *slightly* more manageable problems.)

Comment: The specific problem category is Named Entity Recognition. [Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/language-service/named-entity-recognition/overview) and Google  offers such algorithms. There are several packages in Python that can help, like NTLK and [Spacy](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/06/nlp-application-named-entity-recognition-ner-in-python-with-spacy)

Comment: How does `STRING_SPLIT(Last, ',')` apply to this?  I don't see any commas in your sample inputs.

Comment: Even the libraries the problem isn't trivial. Models are trained for specific data sets and can result in inaccurate predictions. Cloud services cost money but have generally better models, although these may not be the best fit for *your* data. They do allow training based on your data though. OSS libraries are "free" but the models will be simpler and you generally need to be more experienced to train your own models.

Comment: @dougp even if `STRING_SPLIT(Last, ' ')` is used, who says the first string is the name and only the second out of 10 is the surname?

Comment: This is not possible when you consider that many businesses are 2 words and many names are more than 2 words. For example, you have `Big Lots`. That's a business, so how would you distinguish that from `Bob Lotz`? And how would you distinguish `Dicks Sporting Goods` from `Dick Van Dyke`?

Comment: ...and how would you know if a name includes a space, like "Van Dyke" being a last name?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to do this with a simple `CASE` statement.

(SQL Server)

```
with
names (
  FullName
) as (
  select *
  from (
    values 
      ('James Brown')
    , ('Dicks Sporting Goods')
    , ('Charlie Chaplin')
    , ('Five Guys Burgers and Fries')
    , ('Bob Newhart')
    , ('Big Lots')
    , ('George Walker Bush')
  ) q (FullName)
)

select 
  FullName
, case
    when len(replace(FullName, ' ', '')) = len(FullName) - 1
      then substring(FullName, 1, charindex(' ', FullName) - 1)
    else FullName
  end as 'First'
, case
    when len(replace(FullName, ' ', '')) = len(FullName) - 1
      then substring(FullName, charindex(' ', FullName) + 1, len(FullName) - charindex(' ', FullName))
  end as 'Last'
from names
```

| FullName | First | Last |
| --- | --- | --- |
| James Brown | James | Brown |
| Dicks Sporting Goods | Dicks Sporting Goods | NULL |
| Charlie Chaplin | Charlie | Chaplin |
| Five Guys Burgers and Fries | Five Guys Burgers and Fries | NULL |
| Bob Newhart | Bob | Newhart |
| Big Lots | Big | Lots |
| George Walker Bush | George Walker Bush | NULL |

But without an indicator identifying a name as an organization name, you have no way to correctly distinguish between person names and organization names.  (See George Walker Bush and Big Lots in my example.)